# Comparison of UIColors

Tags: iphone, uicolor

I have some code which I can't figure out why it's not working,

```
UIColor *lastColor, *red;
red = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.993 green:0.34444 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0]; 

NSString *chosenColor;

if([lastColor isEqual: red])
{
   chosenColor = @"red";
}
```

I have also found some people making an override of the isEqual method, isEqualtoColor:
But this didn't work either and i fed that one lastColor.CGColor;

Everywhere I've read that isEqual is all you need to compare the UIColors, im currently resorting to an array of strings for red, green and blue and comparing the float value to the CGColorGetComponents(lastColor);

But this isn't working either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[gist.github.com/mtabini/716917](https://gist.github.com/mtabini/716917)

The link above works like a charm. Thanks awfully "Count Chocula" both a delicious source of chocolate and iphone answers :P

I'd click answered to your post but it would more then likly misslead any people wondering on here.

Must have just been a float tolerance.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a Swift version of the accepted answer. I've dropped the `CGColorSpaceRef` comparison as I couldn't find a straightforward way of doing that in swift, but it doesn't seem to impact the results other than in terms of performance.

```
class func colorsConsideredSimilar(color: UIColor, otherColor: UIColor) -> Bool {
    let tolerance: CGFloat = 0.05 // 5%

    let colorRef: CGColorRef = color.CGColor
    let otherColorRef: CGColorRef = otherColor.CGColor

    let componentCount = CGColorGetNumberOfComponents(colorRef)

    let components = CGColorGetComponents(colorRef)
    let otherComponents = CGColorGetComponents(otherColorRef)

    for var i = 0; i < componentCount; i++ {
        let difference = components[i] / otherComponents[i]

        if (fabs(difference - 1) > tolerance) {
            return false
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are grabbing the pixel color from a CGContext with an RGB color space, then it may not match that used by the UIColor class. The pixel values in direct memory references into a CGContext are going to be 0-255 (in an RGB). Depending on the palette of colors you want to compare to, I would probably approach this using uint8_t values to avoid float and perform generalized comparisons based on the dominant values in RGB

Comment: Not sure to be honest, got it from this website <http://www.markj.net/iphone-uiimage-pixel-color/> on train so can't trail through it ATM its pretty low level if I recall.

Comment: OK, the link doesn't show but I'm pretty certain if you are getting pixel colors from a UIImage then you are reading into a copy of that image moved into an RGB color based context. The uint8_t compare will be much less confusing since you avoid float compare issues

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually initializing the red variable? This should work:

```
if ([lastColor isEqual:[UIColor redColor]]) {
  /* … */
}
```

Comment: Yeah this is a custom red colour not the default redColor, so e.g.     + (UIColor *)colorWithRed:(CGFloat)red green:(CGFloat)green blue:(CGFloat)blue alpha:(CGFloat)alpha;
Im printing the values out and they are both exactly the same...exactly...but the isEqual just ignores that fact.

Comment: That's odd. This works for me:


 UIColor *aColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];
 NSLog(@"%d", [aColor isEqual:[UIColor redColor]]);

If the colours have exactly the same components, -isEqual should work without problem. Have you checked *all* the components, including alpha?

Comment: yeah but im not comparing to redColor, if i do what your saying if([color isEqual: [UIColor red]]) i get an [*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[UIColor redC]: unrecognized selector sent to class]

Comment: This is the NLog out put from the colors, color UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.968627 0.0941176 0 1, red : UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.968627 0.0941176 0 1.....and like i said doing if([color isEqual: red]) just doesnt work.

Comment: That's truly weird. Have you tried using Quartz instead? if (CGColorEqualToColor([lastColor CGColor], [red CGColor])) { etc.

Comment: Yeah, afraid so, like i said originally tried two or three different ways, but this is the most spoken about one.

Comment: OK, I'll admit that I'm starting to lose faith :-) I wonder whether there are some floating point inaccuracies that are masking the problem. Try using this function: https://gist.github.com/716917 and let's see if it's just a matter of some tolerance.

Answer (score 0):

`-[UIColor isEqual:]` is the built-in way to compare colours. However, you must remember that while two colours may appear the same to your eyes on a particular device, they may differ mathematically and so compare unequal. Two colours that appear different to your eyes (for example, "pure red" in RGB vs. "pure red" in CMYK) may, upon conversion to a neutral colour space for comparison, compare equal.

Colour spaces are a b_*_* like that. :)

If you tell us *why* you want to compare two colours, we can possibly provide you with a better solution than direct comparison.

**In response to your comment:** Don't base your user interface hit testing on the colour of individual or even multiple pixels. Their absolute values can change based on the device colour space, leading to false positives and negatives. Rather, you can define "hotspot" regions by placing invisible `UIButton` objects in your interface, or better yet, by using something more flexible like `CGPath` and testing if a touch falls within its bounds. Something like the following might work:

```
@interface HotSpottyView : UIView {
    @private NSMutableDictionary *hotspots;
}
- (void)addHotspot: (CGPathRef)path withBlock: (void (^ handler)(void));
@end


@implementation HotSpottyView
- (id)initWithFrame: (CGRect)frameRect {
    self = [super initWithFrame: frameRect];

    if (self) {
        self->hotspots = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }

    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder: (NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithFrame: frameRect];

    if (self) {
        self->hotspots = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [self->hotspots release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)addHotspot: (CGPathRef)path withBlock: (void (^ handler)(void)) {
    CGPathRef immutablePath = CGPathCreateCopy(path);
    if (immutablePath) {
        [self->hotspots setObject: handler forKey: (id)immutablePath];
        CGPathRelease(immutablePath);
    }
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *t = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint loc = [t locationInView: self];
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.bounds, loc)) {
        for (id path in self->hotspots) {
            if (CGPathContainsPoint((CGPathRef)path, NULL, loc, FALSE)) {
                void (^ handler)(void) = [self->hotspots objectForKey: path];
                handler();
            }
        }
    }
}
@end
```

Comment: Im comparing the pixel color at touch and passing that to a viewcontroller then will display an appropriate page.