# Swift - Check if Array<AnyObject> contains UIColor

Tags: arrays, swift, swift2, uicolor

I came across little problem, I was googling several hours, but couldn't find solution.

I store multiple types of values in an array - usually String and UIColor. In one of my functions, I need to check if another array contains certain String or UIColor. I never know ahead if it will contain one object or the other or both. My method below always picks up only the String, but never finds the UIColor, even though I am 100% sure it's there. Even "print" shows the color is present, but it always gets ignored.

How can I correctly check if an array contains UIColor please?

```
// roundItem comes from Array<AnyObject> and reads: UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.160784 0.501961 0.72549 1
let btnInfo: Array<AnyObject> = dict["btn\(key)"]!

if ((btnInfo as NSArray).containsObject(roundItem as AnyObject)) {

            correctAnswer += 1
        }
```

This code above will increment the count if the string is matching, but if the color is matching according to the "print" it will not increment, console print:

btnInfo: [UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.160784 0.501961 0.72549 1]

roundItem: UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.160784 0.501961 0.72549 1

I tried another version, but it crashes:

```
     for item in (btnInfo as NSArray) {

            if item is UIColor {

                print("is UIColor")

                if ((roundItem as! UIColor).isEqual( item as! UIColor)){
                    correctAnswer += 1
                }
            }
            else if  item is String{

                print("is String")

                if roundItem as! String == item as! String{
                    correctAnswer += 1
                }
            }
        }
```

Console print:

Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x10fa332c8) to 'UIColor' (0x11167a268).

I tried do extension with Equatable, but it is crashing also with AnyObject.

How can I compare the stored UIColors or how to convert the UIDeviceRGBColorSpace to another format please?

Answer (score 2):

Given an array like this

```
let list:[AnyObject] = ["Hello", UIColor.whiteColor(), 123, UIColor.redColor()]
```

### Contains

You can check if `list` contains a given color

```
let result = list.contains { ($0 as? UIColor) == UIColor.whiteColor() }
```

### Colors

You can extract the colors and put them into an array of `UIColor(s)`

```
let colors = list.flatMap { $0 as? UIColor }
```

> [UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 1 1, UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 0 0 1]

### Color indexes

You can also extract the color indexes and put them into an array of `Int(s)`

```
let colorIndexes = list.enumerate().filter { $0.element is UIColor }.map { $0.index }
```

> [1, 3]

### Not colors

Finally you can also retrieve the elements that are **not** colors and put them into an array of `AnyObject(s)`

```
let notColors = list.filter { !($0 is UIColor) }
```

*Thanks @dfri*

> [Hello, 123]

Comment: For the last `is` check, as an alternative use `... { !($0 is UIColor) }` in the `filter` closure.

Comment: @dfri: More essential, I like it. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks. It still leaves me with the problem of comparing the UIColors and if they're matching. Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. Basically, I am trying to detect, if the UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.160784 0.501961 0.72549 1 from one array is matching record in another array UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.160784 0.501961 0.72549 1. The print method tells me they're matching, but I can't compare it via the code...

Comment: @Alessign since the rgb values are floating point values, you'd need to apply some tolerance when comparing the equality of them (generally: be careful when in the subject of floating point arithmetics). If this is your purpose, this thread is kind of a duplicate of [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286438/comparision-of-uicolors): see if the answers there can help you out. For a good ref.  on the subject of floatating pt. arithm., see e.g. [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is no guarantee that if `item` is `UIColor` `roundItem` is also `UIColor` so you might check

```
if item is UIColor && roundItem is UIColor { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the effort, especially @appzYourLife - nice clean solution for sorting.

I found what was wrong. I put the two arrays in simple test and it turned out, that the "roundItem" was cast as a String, not as a UIColor, that's why it was ignored as UIColor each time. I was retrieving this array from NSUserDefaults and that's where the error message came from pointing on

Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x10fa332c8) to 'UIColor' (0x11167a268)

...as it was stored as a String. So I made few changes and stored the colors in dictionary as UIColor with string key, which I am comparing and it works now. If I test the code above with both arrays which are storing UIColors (not from NSUserDefaults), it works well, so it still can be used if someone finds it helpful.

Thanks again

Best,
A.